# admin rating for products

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

i have added another rating to product page named `Admin Rating` which is editable by admin.
i created an attribute `admin_rating` and assign it to the attribute set, and entered a digit for this attribute from 0 to 100, one star is equal to 20 and five stars to 100.

i edited this file:

```
\app\design\frontend\your package \your theme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

and added this code into it:

```
<div class="rating-box">
 <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_product->getAdminRating();?>%;"></div>
</div>
```

every thing is fine but i want change admin stars view (they are stars and i want them to be other things like circles or ...), but `class="rating-box"` contains one kind of shapes and when i change it, both of the ratings will change.

how can i do that?
i will thankful if you describe it by details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the code you added and change `<div class="rating-box">` to `<div class="admin-rating-box">`.  Now you can style the two ratings separately.  For example, in the theme's `styles.css` file copy the old style to make:

```
.admin-rating-box { width:69px; height:13px; font-size:0; line-height:0; background:url(../images/bkg_admin_rating.gif) 0 0 repeat-x; text-indent:-999em; overflow:hidden; }
.admin-rating-box .rating { float:left; height:13px; background:url(../images/bkg_admin_rating.gif) 0 100% repeat-x; }
.ratings .admin-rating-box { float:left; margin-right:3px; }
```